# How to get match[1] with grep?

Tags: grep

Here's my code so far...

```
cat config.json | grep -Po '"server"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"'
```

But I just want the part within (parentheses). I can't use a look-behind because it's variable-length. What are my options?

Sample input 1:

```
{"debug":false,"server":"dev-dutch","env":"dev"}
```

Sample input 2:

```
{
  "debug": false,
  "server": "dev-dutch",
  "env": "dev"
}
```

Desired output for both:

```
dev-dutch
```

I know there are probably safer/better ways to parse JSON, but I want to do this in shell, and it should run on both Ubuntu and FreeBSD without installing any external programs, so I'm OK with a `grep` hack.

Comment: @Cyrus Good call. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '"server": *"\K[^"]+' file
```

Comment: How does `\K` work? Does it match everything from there until the end or what? Can you add a stop-point? Can't find any docs on this.